# 28 soldiers puzzle

Tags: problem-solving, puzzle

A leader ordered his 28 soldiers to protect the castle , the castle has 4 walls or sides. He wants 9 soldiers to guard each wall. How can the be possible ?

Comment: Two on each corner, five on each side.

Comment: Or nine on a pair of diagonally opposite corners, and given the other 10 soldiers a rest. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way this can work is if soldiers at the corners are considered to guard two walls. In the most symmetric solution, we can then place $2$ soldiers at each corner, and $5$ along the middle of each side (so $2+5+2=9$ protecting each side).
But really any solution in which there are a total of $8$ soldiers at the four corners will work, e.g.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
1&6&2\\6& &4\\2&4&3
\end{array}$$